# Mapbox Studio - Road Exit Shield and Road Number Shield

Tags: mapbox

I'm currently editing my own style in Mapbox Studio and I've selected to show the road number and road exit shields.

I can locate the individual layers for these two but I'm having trouble figuring out what to edit in the style panel to produce what I want to see:

When you zoom out, road number shields remain visible, but there appears to be a step change for the exit number shields - they completely disappear after zooming out less than 14. So I'm looking through each option for a step change at about this value but I can't seem to find anything that has this.

Can anyone advise what I can change to keep the exit number shields visible when zooming out, in a similar style to the road number shields?

Answer (score 1):

When you have the style panel open for the road-exit-shield, at the top right of the window, click Select data (and follow the instruction to expand all layers) then you will see the 'zoom extend' in this window which can be altered.

[style panel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOaAq.png)